# Recurring Membership Price Set payments don't show after first payment

Tags: civimember, civireport, price-sets, recurring-contributions, issues

We have three different membership types configured in a price-set along with an option to add additional contributions. When someone subscribes for membership, they subscribe to all three membership types.

When we pull a bookkeeping transaction report to view the membership payments (our memberships are recurring monthly payments, made through a price-set, so bookkeeping transaction reports are the easiest way to view the line-items), only the initial payment shows all three membership payments. In subsequent payments all membership payments are missing from the report.

When I check this against the member's contribution tab on their contact page, it shows that their payments did go through (as our merchant services reports confirm). However, when I click to View the details of any recurring membership payment after the initial one, none of three memberships appear. The total amount is correctly represented on the summary page, but the system doesn't seem to register the membership payments associated with the price-set.

So while I initially thought this was an issue with the way the Report was representing the data, it appears it's an issue with how CiviCRM processes recurring payments with membership price-sets.

When I checked the Line Items in the Database, the membership items were not recorded after the initial payment. (see last two images- Contribution #1943 is first payment, #2401 is second installment)

I don't know how to recreate this on the demo site since it involves recurring payments, and I haven't found any forum posts or bug reports discussing this. Has anyone else encountered it? Has it been reported and I missed it?

The three images below show one member's payments over three months. The first month is correctly represented, and the next two months are missing the three memberships ($30, $20, $15).

If you have any thoughts, I'm all ears. It's driving our bookkeeper crazy!

Thanks.

[image: bookkeeping transaction report]
[image: detail view of initial membership recurring payment]
[image: detail view of second membership recurring payement]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a good question, but we'll need more information to answer it.  Could you please give us your exact CiviCRM version number?  Depending on your version, you may need to check civicrm_line_item or civicrm_financial_trxn, not civicrm_contribution.

Comment: I'm running 4.5.6 on Drupal 7.32. The two screenshots from the DB are from the civicrm_line_item table, sorry I wasn't clearer on that. The result from civicrm_contribution shows the correct Total Amount ($165) for each contribution (#1943 and #2401), but the devil's in the details with this one.